# Fun with Tikz Dogs

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, tikzlings

I am aware of the many fun uses of LaTeX such as the ever growing [`tikzlings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings) package. Is anyone aware of any package to depict dogs?

#### Edit 1

This may be quite selfish, any idea how to draw a simple German shepherd?. For those unfamiliar with dog breeds, it looks like [this](https://www.insidedogsworld.com/german-shepherd-personalitytrainability/). *Disclosure:* Inspired by @marmot's icon :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is my third answer and my second non-CW answer here :) Don't worry, I'll shut up now.

Because this doesn't relate to the Kaila, I decided to post another answer instead of edit the other post.

---

**1** | [*inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473450/156344)*] For the sake of completeness, let's have some Unicode dogs!

```
% XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setmainfont{Symbola}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption*{Let's go for a Unicode dog!}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{10}{\char"1F415}
        \caption{U+1F415 -- A dog}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{10}{\char"1F436}
        \caption{U+1F436 -- A dog face}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My comment: The dog face (U+1F436) is so sweet! It should be the base of a `tikzlings-dog`, I think.

**2** | [*inspired by [Raaja](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/70891/raaja)*] For the sake of completeness (again), let's have ASCII-art! This is a German Shepherd for GermanShepherd :))

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMNOOXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNk;..oWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0:... lWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'.'...lWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNd..,;,..dMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd..',;:;.dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMk'..',,:c.lWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:.'',,,:l,,0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd..,;::cllc'cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0,.',:ccooldc'xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWWWN0kdlccoKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo..;ccclddddd:;0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMWN0dc:,.....;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;.,cooddxxxddd,cNMMMMMMMMMMN0oc:,;ldko,..:KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.'looodxdxkdoxl'oNMMMMMWN0o:,:ldk000k:..lXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0:,cclodkkdddddxkl;kWMWNOl:;:ldkkkkkOkc..oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNOc;:;;:clllllodxkkkxOX0dc:;lxkkoc:lxkd:..oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNXkoc;,;:::;;:c::ldxddxxxkkxxkO0Oxxc,codko;..:XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0dl:;:ol:::cc:cc:::clodxxxxxOOkOOxc;;'ckkxc,'..kWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWW0oxOOdlllodxkxxxdddoccloddxxxkdcodl,,;,okOd;'..:XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWKcoK0kdxO00KK000Okkkkxddodxddkxl,;o;.:lcodxo:'..xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKccOOxxOKKK00Oxdddddxkkxxdolodxxo,.;,.;ddoooc'..oNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMWMWO;;ddoxO000kxdoloxxxxxkOkkxolodkOx:.,;,cxdolc:'.;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWWNOl.':cok00Okoc:;,;oxxkOOOOOOkdlcdOkd,.,;:cdoc:;;..dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOxxl;,',;:lodkkxl:,;..;;lddkOOO0Oxol:lxxc...'',:c:,'...oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXd:;:;,,;;:::clodoc;...',:,.:lllodxxoloc:oxo. ....,;'.... .xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0l,'',,',;;:looddddlclc;;:clll:,;:codxkkxolldx;.';:ll;.';;'. :XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWKd:'.''..',:ccclooodxkO000OOOOkxocoxkkO000K0Oddkxooddoc;;cloc'. '0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNkc'..'..,,;,,;;;:cloodxOOOOkkkkxdxxk0KKKKKK000K0OkOkkxolclcclo:....xWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0occ::,,,,,;;;,..';;;:cccoxOOOkkkkOO0000KK0KKKK0O000OOOxdoddl,:ll:'...lNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo,kNO:,;,,,''...,:;;;:c:;:clollldkOO0KKKKKK00000OO0OOkkkkko:':lc:;....:XWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWKl:ll,..........,;,,;,,:;;:;'';:coxOKKXXKKK000OO00Okxxkkdc,cxko:;,'.'.,OWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMNOl;...''..''..'',,;'',,'''':o::ccdkO00OO00OO00OOxxxkxo:;lxkkdc;;;',;'lNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOo;'.......'','......,c:dx'.:codkOOkkkkkxddxxooc:;;cdddxxoc;::;,,';OWMMMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWN0dl::;'.........,locdo'..,loddddooooddodxdc:codkOOkxdo:;;;:;''.'dNMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXKkl;,;;:clddccc' .',;:coxxxxxkOOkxkkxxkOkO00Odol;.',::''..,kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMWx:cdxdodooo;'..,cc:coodkOOOkxxxxxxxkkkk00Okxdolc;,;;;;''...kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0;;oddolc,''..'codxxxxkkO0OkxxkkkkOkkO0OkkOxddlcl:',;,'..,..,0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMx,cddol:'  .:odddxOkdxOOOkxxxkOkOKK0kO00Okxdodc;cc;'.,,..,;'.cXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo'cdxo,.'',okxdxOOOxxO0OkxkkxkOO000OOO0OOOxooo,.clc;.,;'..;:..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd;oxxl'l0kkOkkkO0OxxOOOkxkOOOO000O00000OOkoloc'.::;,.';,...;l'cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd;dkk:,k0OO0OOO0OxxkkkkkO00000KKOO0000Okkdlcl;',;;,'.',,',..oodNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMO,:xk::OK0K0000OkOOOkOO000K00KKK0OKX0Okkdoolc;,;;;;'',,.;c'.ck0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWNd'ckccKK000O0OO0XK0O0KK00KKK00000K0kkkxolc;,',,'''.',',:o;.cKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWW0o0WXx::'cKK000K0O0KKKKKKK00KKKXK00000kkkxdl:;,',,..''.''.,'::.dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0o:dKNNNXxdOK0000000KKKKKKKK0O0KKKKKKK00kkkdc;'.',::,,;'..''''kKOXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNx:,l0XXNNXNNNX0KKKKKKKKKKXKKK0O0KKK0KXKK0Okkoc,'..',,;','...'.'xWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNk:;lxKXXXXXXXXXKKXKKKKKKKKKXKKK00KKKXKKKK0OOkdl;,,'.'','','..'.'xWWMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo;llcxKXXXKXXXK00KXK0KKKKKKKKXX00KKKXXK0K000Okd;':;..',,'.',,,'.,KWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKl:;cxKXXXXKXXXXKXKK0KKKKKXXKXXK0KXXXXKKK0000Ox:':c,..,;,,,;:;c:.,KWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO:,lOXKXXXXXKXXXXXXKKKKKKXXKXXXK0KXXKXXK000000kd;:c;,',:,;:ldddxx,'OWWWWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNd';kKxx0XNNXKKXXXXXXXXXXKXXXKXX00KKKKKKK00KK000Odol:c::lccoxkkkkkxo,cXWMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd':kx:cOXXNXKKXXXXXXKKXKKXXXXXXKKKXXXXK00O0K0Okkxxxoooodxkkkkkxxkkkxd;lXWWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKclKx,c0XNNNXKKXXKKXK00KKXXXXXXXKXNXXXKKK00K0kxxdxOklokkxxkkOOkxxxkkxxo;lXWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXN0,:OKXNNNKKKKK0KKKKKXXXNXXXKXXNXXXK00K00K0xooldkc,okkkOOkOkkOxddxxdc'c0WWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo'xKXNNNK0KK0KKKKKKKKXXXXXXKKXNXKKK000000Oddl;ld,:OOOO0OOOkkOkxddoo:'xWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWl,ONWWWKdOXK0KKK0KKKXXXXXKKKKXXKKKK00000Odod;'ol,oOO0K0O0Oxxkkkxl;,,.oWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMx:0WWMWxcOK0KXX00KKKKKKKKXK0XK00000OOOkxoccc':o,:O00KK0OOkxxdddd:.';:0WWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKo0WWMKc;k00KXXK0K0000000K0000O0Okxxxddo;'''cd:,x000KKOkkxxdlllc..c;,kWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXNMMM0,,xOO0XX0OO00000OOO0OOO00kdoxdcl:'..:kddOK00KK0Okxoolcll;.lxo,.l0WWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO';xkkO0000OO0000kk00OOOkOxlll:::'..cO0KXXKKK0Okxdoc:::llcoOkl,..'oXWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0,;OxokkkKK0OkkOOkkOkxkkkd:,::;:,..cOKXXXXKK0Okxddc,,;ldxO0Ox:'....,dXWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo,kk:oxk00kddoxxxoloool:'';;;,..:dO0KXXKK0KOxdocc;,coxO00kxo;''.''..,oKWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMNkOO;,clokdllooc;,;ll,.;;,,'..;d0KKKKKKK0Okocc:;,;lxkO0KOl::,,,.',....'o0WWWMWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWK;.;::llllc;,'':;.':lc;';lx0KKKK0KKKK0xl:;;,,cxkkOOkkd:,,,''.',''.,'.'ckXWWWMWMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWl.;;;cccc,',',,';lodxxkKXKKXKK00KK0Odl;,,,;lxOOOkxoc:;,,'''..,,,,,;,'..;xNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl.',.:c:c;',,:lddxxkOKXXXKKK00000kxo:,,,;;lxOOkdolc;,.'''','.;;',;'',,,..;kNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNl.'','':::,':ldkOOOOO0XNXX0000Oxdo:,,,;;,:llxOkdccl:,'.',',;,;;,,',,''.,'...lKWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMWWWMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO';Od;c,',;::oxkO0KOdkKXNXK0KOkdl:;'..;,'::;okkdc::;'','',,;;,,;,'.'',;;,''...;OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWMMWWWXK00000KXWWMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNl'xX0xxd;.,cxOOOKK0d,oXXXKKK0kdc;,,'''',;;'lOxll::;,'',;::::;;:;,,,..';c:,;:;'.cXMWMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMWWNNWXkocc:,''''',;:lodkKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'cXX00O0o':xkxO0K0k:'xXKKKKOkdlc:;;,''',l,'dxlclol:;,,,;ccc:;;c:,,;'.'';:;,;;,,,dNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWN0xkkoc,.''',,',,,;;;;;,'',:lxKWMWMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:.kNXK00Kk;,kkld000O:'xKK000OOxxl::;.';,:;.lkdooddollcc:::clcc::c:;;;;,',::;,''.;oONWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWWXxc;,;,.';,............',,,,,;,';cdKWMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO':KNXX00K0c'xO:lkkkk:'x00KKK00Oxoc;,',,;l';OOOOkxxkkkxddoodolcc:::::::,,;,;;'','.;kNWWMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWXd,,:;...;:,'.'..........',,,,',,,:;;oXMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:'xXXXXKKK0o'l0c;xkkk;'x00KKK000Oko:;:clxo,oK0000OOO000OOkkxkkkxo:::;:::;;;;;;'''. cNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWO;',;,'',,,'''..... .'...';cl:;:okKNWWWMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'cKXXXXXK00k:oKl,xOkx,'d000KK0000OkxdxkkOl,xK00000000000OOOkkk00kooollcll:;;;c:,;,..kWMWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWXl',,...':,.''........,,,;cllo:;dXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:,OXXXKXKK000kOKo'lOkd''x00K0KK000000OOOO0l,x00KK0KK0OO000OO0OkOOkxdddddoolcc:::;;:. cNMWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMWWWK:.:;......'''''....,;,;:ccclocldOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.oXXKKKKKKKK0000O;'dOl.;k00K0KXKK0OO00O000d;d00KKK00K00000O00OO0Oxxkkkxddddddddollc,.'OMWWMWWMMMMMMMMMWWWNl.',''.'..',,,,'',',,,';cc:cdkkoc0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK,,OXXKKKKKK000000xl,'l,.d000KKKK00000K00OO0k:oK0KK000KKK0000KK0O000OOOOOkxxol:::;;'.. oWWWWWWWMWWMMMMMMWWx..,';,','',,,;,.',,,;;:c::lxOKd,xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd,xKKXKK00KKK0000o,oKd'.l00000KKKKKK0000000kc;dK0KKKKKKKK0O0KKK0KK0OO00Okkkkkkkkxolc:,. .cONWWWWWWWWMMMMWN0;.'',;',,;;'',''.'',,;:cc:lxOO0c;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0;cKK0KKK0000OO00l'oNWX;'kK000KKKKKK00000000k,:k00KKKKKKKK000000KK00OkOOkOOkdooccloooolc,'..cdxXWWWWWWWWWXxl'.:,'',,''.';,..',;::::::oxxk00:cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo,kXKKKKK00kxO0k;'dNWWx.:0KKKKKKKXKK00KK00Oxd,cO00KKKKKKK00KKKK0OO00kkOkxl::::::;::,;;;,,,,.''.;OWWWWWWWWk;,.',.',,,,,;;;'.';c::c::cloxOKX0;cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO,lKKKK000kdxO0x;;OWWMX:.xXKKK0KKKKK000000x,,dooOO0KXK00K00KKXKK00O00Odc:::llc:,'..'',,'.';,',;;.'kWWWWWWWd',..'','';;:::,.';::;,;:coodkKKKk':NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN:'kK00000xlx00x,cXWMMMO';0XKK00KK000OO00Od,;xO0000K0KXKK0O0KXK00000ko:codxxo:,,'.'','.''..,;,,',:.;KWWWWWXc';...'''',,,,,'';::;,,:ccldk0KKXx.cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd'oKKKK00xoxO0d'lXMMMMMx.lXKKKKKK000OkO00l'cOkk0K00KK0KK000KXNXKKK0xccloxxol;'..',''''.',,''',;'.,,.dWWWWWK;.'...'..''',''.,,;,,:lccloxOKKKXx.oWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0,;0K0K00kodOOl,dNMMMMMNc'kXK0KK00KKOkO0k:.,xOkO0K00KKKXKKKKKKKKKK00xlc:cloc,'''''','.......'','.',,.lNWWWW0,.''......,;;''::;,;lc:;;ldOKKKXKc,OWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc'kK0KK00dokkc,xWMMMMMM0':0XK00KKKK0kk0k,.:cc:ck0K000KXXKXKKX0O0000d:cxxol:'''.'',:,.'...''..''''.,:.:XWWWWO..''....',''',c:'';ccc::ldk0K0KXk;dOkNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.lXK0KKKxcxOl,xWMMMMMMMd.dXKK0KKKKOkk0k,.o000d,'xK0O0KXKKXXK0KKKKk::dkocc;'''..,,','.....',..','..cl.:XWWWWk..''',,',,..','..;cclllodkO00KXKloNkcOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0,;OXKKK00dokl,xWMMMMMMMWl'kKKXKK0K0kkOO;.o000OOo.;k000XK0KKKKKK00O:c0k;,;,;;'.,,,,'.......;,..,;,.,l;'xWWWWWx..'.',','..''....,clloodkOO0XXXxlKWO:kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc,OXKKK00Oxxc,xWMMMMMMMMK::OKKKK000OOOOc'o0K0OOOk:.o000KKKKKKK000Kxlkd;,;;;,',;:,''...'...'....,,..:c'cKWWWWXc .''',,,'.'...';:cllllldkkxOKKXKXWXc,OMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo'dXKKKKK0OOo,xWWMWWMMMWWk;xXXKKK00OOO0o'oKK00OO00o.cK00KKXKKXKKKKKKOc';;::'',::;'''...'......'....,cc,xWWWWNl. ';,,,''''...';loll::codoldO0KXNNXo.oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo,o0KK0KK00Ox,lNWKkdxkXWWNl;OXXK00KKOkOx'cKKKK00OO0x';kO0KKKKKKKKXXXXd';:;:'',;;;,'....''..,..,,',;,:d:,OWWWXl...,:;'',,'..';ccc:cc::lcclxO00KXNNd'lXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl;xKKXKKK0O0k;,xxccodl:;cxd'lKXKK0KK0OOk:'c0XKK000O0k,,k0KKKKKK0KXKKXO',l::,';;;,''....''';,.',:;',:,:o;oWWNk;....',',,''''..',:::;;:loddxkkO0KNXo,oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWKc;kXKXXKK000Ol.,,:dKXXXKko:',kXK00KKKOO0c;xl:kOO00000k;:O00XXXKKKKKKKKl.lko;';:,'''.'',,;'',,;c::;',,'oxdkxl;'..''.'..,'.'..';;;:cc:;coldkkOOOKXO:;kNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNk;cOKKKXXK0000d. 'dKK0000KKXx,lKKK00KKK0Od',lc:cdkOOOO0k:l000KKKKKKKKKKk,,k0o,';;..''''';;;;,':doc:,:l'.............',,,,...',,,;:cc:::coxOOOOOK0o:dX00WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0ddONMMKl,o0KK00KXK00kd;.;OK000kdk0KO:;kKKK00KK0Od',OKKK00K0OOO0Ocl000KK0KKKKKXNx.;O0c',c;.';;,;::;cc,:odlc:::'';'.......'..',,'....',,:lc;,,,:cdxxkOO0xlod0WX:oWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNOc,:cclll;cOKKKK00KK0d:;,.:0X0kkl;ckKKl'o00KK000OOkc.lKKKK00KK0OO00d:lkOO00KK00KXNo.lK0l.,;.,:;;:clll:,cdddodl'..''......''',,,,,'..'',;:;'',;:cloloxk0KkdkKXNKc;OMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOc;lOXXXOocdKXKKK00KKKo'c0x':OOOOc.lO0Kx':OK0K0000Okx;:O00000KXXKK0KK0xoclok0K0OO0KXl.dKkl';,';;::ldxxdclxxxkxl'.''..'..''.''','.''....''...':c:c::ldxk00KKXXXXx;;OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk:;oOKK0kxOKK0KK00000KKx,oXNk:;,,:c..:okx;;OKKKK00000Oc,xKKXKKKKXKKKKKXXXKkc:cxKK0OO0Kl'xKkoco:',:ccoxkOkxkkxkk:..;;,,,,',,''''.....''..,:ccc:;,;:clxkkO00KXXXXk::xXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMXl;oOKK0d:,:cok0000KK0KKk,:0X0OOOxlc:;,;:;.,kKKKXK00K00O::k00OkOkkkdocclooox0Oolllx0K00Kd,oKOxxOl.,coxOOOOkkkkkd,.';:;,,,,,;;,,;,''..,;;;,;c:;;:clldxxkkOKKXNNXxc:dKWWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMWWWNdc0XK00o.,kKOkk0000KKKKk,.o0OOOOOOOO00000o'oKKKKK0KKK00d',c:::;::;:c:clodxxxkOOkkxllodxxOo:xOkO0d,;dkOKK00OO0Oo'.,;;;,;;'.',;;;;;;,,'',,,,;cccclooodkkO0XXXKkoclodxkk0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMWWNNXK00l,cccc;.;OXXKKKKK00Oxxo'.:kOOkkOkkk00KK0l.:0KKK000K0KOx:;k0OOOOOOkkO0OkxxkxkkkOkkkOxc,:ok0xk00O0OolxO0KXX0O00o',c:::ldoo:,,;::::ccccccolcc:cc:codxkOKKKKOxolldOk:;oKWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMWWNXXK00Oxdo:;;,;ccloollc::;;;;:dkkkkkOOO0KKXXOc'lOKKK0000KKKd'.oNNNNNX0O0000kkOkkkkxolc:::clx0KKKK0K00KK0OKKKKKKKKKd.;kkdooddxollllc::::::::cccclcldxk0KKXXXXNXxookXN0:;oddKMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMWWWNXXXXXXK00kkxdollodkOO000KKXXXXNNNNWWNXx,,dKKK000000KOo:.;0WMWXK000Kkl;',;;;;,,,:codk00K0O0KKKKK0KKKKKKKKKK0KXklk0kdoxOkkkxdxxxxkxxxxkkkkkOOOO00KXXXNX0kxxk0XWWNOl;:ldKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMWMW0c;lx0KK000KKKK0l,:c0WWWXKKKKkc,.,oxdooodk0KKK0K0O0OO000K00KXOod0XXKxooddddoloo;,;clooddkO00000000K0KXXXKK0kxxkkxodkKNWNWWKlcOdlOWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0K0Oklo00O000KKKKKKKO:lNWWWWWXKK0o'':okKX0O000KKK00000000K0OOOO00x,.'::cl:,'':oddxxkxddolc::::::::cccllllodoodoododk0K000KXNNXXKKXNNOkKWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXd;..,:cldOOxOK0KKKK00Kd,dWWWWWWNX0c.;ok0kocldO0K00000OO0K0000OOOkl;,;ldollllloxOO0000OkO0000OOOOxxxdxxxxxddxxdxOOOOOO0OkO0KXXXNNNXNXXNNXXNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0:,,,o0XKOdc:::ccdO000K0:,0WWWWXKKKk;,xKx:;:d0KKKK0OO000000kkkkkd:,;lxkOOOOO0000K0000000OOO00OO0KKKKXKKXXXXXXNXXXXKKXXXXKK0XNWMMMMMMWWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMWO;;clOXXXOdOOO0OOdlk00O0d.cKKKKKKKKXk,:kc'ck0K00KKkloO0000OOkxdl:;:ok00KXKKNNNWMMMWWWWNNNNNNNNXXNNWWWWWWWWWWWWWMMMWWWWWWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWKc:cl0XXKd:d0KKKKKOxOK00O;.d000OOOO00Oc..'xXKKK00Od,;x00000dcc:;:okO0KXKKKXNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNNNNNXk:;OXKKd,o00KKKKk:o0000o.c0kk00OOO000Oxl:lk00KKO:.;dOOxolc:lxOOOO00KKXXNNNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXXXKKXKk::odc'l0KXXXXk':OOkxl.,dOOOOOkkxxkxxkkd;;clcc:,',:cc:cldxk0KK00KXXXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNNNNNXK0Odcc:',:;;::c'.';,'.':dxkkOO0Okk00000000OkxxxkOkxkkkOkOKKKXNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWNXKOolodddxOxlodxOO0KKKKXXXXXXNWWNNXXXKKKXXXKK0KKKXXNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMWWWWWWMMMWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Image Source: [here](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/78/80/3b/78803bbd25d0620284546ebafbd59491.jpg)

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: The Unicode dog looks very well rendered

Comment: To someone who downvoted this, may I ask why?

Answer (score 20):

Answer dedicated to David:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(0,30){woof}
\put(44,20){\circle{6}}
\put(50,30){ \line(1,3){5} }
\put(40,30){ \line(-1,3){5} }
\put(30,30){ \line(1,3){5} }
\put(60,30){ \line(-1,3){5} }
\put(43,30){\line(1,0){10} }
\put(33,21){\line(0,0){10} }
\put(23,11){\line(0,0){10} }
\put(20,21){ \line(1,0){10} }
\put(20,11){ \line(1,0){80} }
\put(63,30){\line(1,0){40} }
\put(100,30){ \line(2,5){8} }
\put(100,10){ \line(1,5){8} }
\put(50,10){ \line(-1,-3){4} }
\put(60,-2){ \line(-1,3){4} }
\put(80,10){ \line(-1,-3){4} }
\put(90,-2){ \line(-1,3){4} }
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image: dog]

Comment: To use `picture` it was good idea to make it minimalist (not realistic).

Comment: ooh you did not sign it  `p.p. D. Carlisle` :-)

Comment: upvoted. Clearly the best answer here.

Answer (score 18):

For [the Laika dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laika), one of the greatest dogs in human history:

[image]

The code is nearly 28000 lines long, so I can't paste it here. You can go [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vuvandung03/TikZ-figures/master/Laika/main.tex) to see the code.

That code is generated using Inkscape.

**Edit:** This image is taken from [here](https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.411612078.6510/raf,750x1000,075,t,fafafa:ca443f4786.u1.jpg).

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faIcon{dog}

\faIcon{hotdog}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) The hotdog is way too big compared with the dog :))

Comment: @JouleV No, it's a _really_ tiny canine.

Comment: @JouleV, and the size is OK, since the dog should be inserted inside the bread.... lol

Answer (score 15):

My [`ducksay`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ducksay) features a dog:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{ducksay}

\begin{document}
\ducksay[dog,vpad=1]{This is dogsay!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you have access to software with edge detection (e.g. [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeDetect.html)), you can take any image, export the coordinates of the edges to a file ('Table' format) and then plot the coordiantes using `pgfplotstable` and the '`only marks`' key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{outf.txt}{\dog} % Coordinates exported from Mathematica
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            anchor=origin, 
            rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)}, % Needed to correct the orientation
            xmin=0,xmax=400,
            ymin=0,ymax=500,
            xticklabels=\empty,
            yticklabels=\empty]
            \addplot[only marks, mark=*, mark size=0.1, draw=black] table {\dog};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: dog]

But I'm not aware of any specific dog-depicting LaTeX package :).

Answer (score 13):

The question is surly a xy-problem: Why would you want to draw a dog if you could have a cat instead? So here is the answer to the real problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \cat
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

(needs the development version of the tikzlings package, available from https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings)

Comment: Time to add the better cats to `tikzlings`, isn't it?

Answer (score 11):

I borrow this dog figure from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112264/156344). As the code is not mine, I make this answer as community wiki.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, blue] plot [smooth, tension=0] coordinates { (3.666667,15.1) (2.833333,14.9) (2.233333,14.36667) (2.133333,13.96667) (1.733333,13.96667) (1.433333,13.36667) (1.433333,13) (1.566667,12.63333) (2.066667,12.33333) (2.466667,12.2) (2.766667,12.2) (3,12.33333) (3.333333,12.3) (3.533333,12.03333) (3.666667,11.4) (4.033333,10.56667) (4,9.133333) (4.833333,7.3) (5.3,4.4) (5.333333,3.4) (5.233333,2.7) (4.7,2.466667) (4.633333,2.1) (5.133333,1.933333) (5.6,1.933333) (5.833333,2.033333) (6.033333,2.333333) (6.166667,3.166667) (6.3,3.3) (6.366667,5.366667) (6.566667,6.966667) (8.233334,7.133333) (11.03333,8.033334) (11.6,7.733333) (12.26667,6.6) (13.3,5.5) (14.06667,4.933333) (14.6,4.3) (14.73333,3.966667) (14.7,2.866667) (14.6,2.666667) (14.23333,2.466667) (14.16667,2.066667) (14.33333,1.933333) (14.66667,1.9) (15.13333,1.966667) (15.4,2.2) (15.73333,4.833333) (15.33333,5.4) (14.6,6.1) (14.26667,7.033333) (14,9.8) (13.83333,10.43333) (13.66667,10.66667) (14.03333,11.36667) (14.03333,11.63333) (13.66667,11.66667) (13.2,11.2) (12.1,11.43333) (10.4,11.4) (8.366667,11.53333) (7.966667,11.83333) (7.233333,11.96667) (6.966667,12.2) (6.666667,12.23333) (5.7,13.6) (4.966667,14.26667) (4.933333,14.53333) (4.733333,14.73333) (4.366667,14.9) (4.3,15.03333) (3.7,15.1) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ps. I'm looking for a `tikzlings` dog from samcarter and a `picture` dog from David Carlisle!

Comment: I sent a duck understudy to supply the requested picture.

Answer (score 10):

DISCLAIMER: I am a vegetarian. Here is a(nother) hot dog. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[top color=brown!20!yellow,bottom color=brown!50](-4,0) arc(180:270:1) -- (3,-1) arc(-90:0:1);
 \draw[fill=brown!20!yellow](-3,0.5) arc(90:270:1 and
 0.5) -- (3,-0.5) arc(-90:90:1 and 0.5) -- cycle;
 \draw[top color=brown!80!yellow,bottom color=brown](-4,1.25) arc(90:270:1 and
 0.75) -- (4,-0.25) arc(-90:90:1 and 0.75) -- cycle;
 \draw[top color=brown!20!yellow,bottom color=brown!50]
 (-4,1.25) arc(180:270:1 and 0.5) -- (3,0.75) arc(-90:00:1 and 0.5) 
 arc(0:90:1 and 1)-- (-3,2.25) arc(90:180:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX Indeed ....

Answer (score 8):

Here is a white head dog (not the Whitehead's pet, who had a pig) viewed from above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
$<\kern -4.3pt \rule[-.4pt]{1pc}{6.4pt}\rule[2.5pt]{.5pc}{1pt}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

**DISCLAIMER**: This answer is inspired by [this post by @samcarter in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49356063#49356063). There can (IMHO) be no doubt that the by far cutest dogs are the prairie dogs. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\let\prairiedog\marmot
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=pi]{\prairiedog}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Dog's ice cream (fresh from oven)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linecap=1,linewidth=2,linecolor=brown](-7,0)(7,10)
    \psline(-5,1)(5,1)
    \psline(-3.5,2.5)(3.5,2.5)
    \psline(-2,3.5)(2,3.5)
    \pscustom{\psbezier(-.5,4.5)(1,4.5)(-.5,7)(1.5,5)}
    \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=2pt}
    \multips(-.5,7)(1,0){3}{\psbezier(0,0)(-1,.5)(1,1.5)(0,2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to draw some flies.